# Почему не работает регулярка на c#?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярка:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("<div class=\"eTitle\" style=\"padding-bottom:3px;\"><span style=\"font-size: 14pt; font-family: Arial; color: rgb(128, 0, 0);\">(.*)</span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection mc = regex.Matches(text);
```

Пробовал экранировать и кавычками и слэшем в итоге получается исходный код html, что и нужно по задумке, но большое "НО" в переменной text хранится код в точно таком же виде вместе со слэшами именно поэтому я решил привести регулярку к виду, думая что это переломит ход событий:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("<div class=\\\"eTitle\\\" style=\\\"padding-bottom:3px;\\\"><span style=\\\"font-size: 14pt; font-family: Arial; color: rgb(128, 0, 0);\\\">(.*)</span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Но все равно, как была коллекция пустая так таковой и осталась. Между дивом и спаном находится обычный текст. Если написать регулярку попроще, например "(.*)", то все работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, люди добрые в чем проблема?

Comment: Регулярки не подходят для парсинга HTML

Comment: @Сергей через поиск по подстроке тогда делать?

Comment: Как вариант. Или чем-нибудь специализрованным типа `HTML-Agility Pack`

Comment: @Сергей, спасибо, буду изучать!

Comment: [Не стоит парсить HTML регэкспами](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454)